# MONTH SQL filtrar por mes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Deseo escoger las filas que cumplan la condición de fecha solo del mes, mi formato fecha es por ejemplo 17/02/2021 y como condicion deseo obtener todos loos registros que coincidan con 02.
Intente con SELECT Month('07/02/2021') AS Month; pero no puedo hacerlo.

Comment: En el método `month` deberías pasar el nombre de la columna y esto evaluarlo en el `where` con la condición que indicas

Comment: SELECT month('2021-02-22') as mes; devuelve 2, select month('22/02/2021') as mes; devuelve NULL en MySql 8, podrías tener el problema en el formato de la fecha.